# Conundrum - need to get viewport size in PHP (or any other way around it)

Tags: php, javascript, viewport

Basically, I currently have a site that's written in javascript, but I've decided to rewrite in mainly PHP. The main bit I'm replacing uses spry to read values off an xml dataset into javascript variables.

PHP with mySQL can easily take on the jobs I'm using spry for, but there's one other part of the script I'd like to make server-side.

What currently goes on is that as the page loads, my function decides what size a picture should be, and therefore what size to get on the server. There are five files of different sizes, and it chooses the smallest one where it doesn't have to upscale (but it can downscale). It combines this with some information from spry, and sets the src of an img element, which is not previously set (this is part of what I hate about my current setup).

I've done my googling, and I know the problem - PHP parses server-side, at that point it can't know the screen size.

I can do without - I would either keep my existing javascript for this task, which is a bit unstable, or just use one size of image, which would just make my site not as good.

I'm just wondering if any expert has a trick up their sleeves for having php decide which image to embed. I'm guessing there's nothing the browser sends when it first requests the site.. that woulda showed up in my googling..

I should mention, I've not done any PHP apart from a simple thing where there's a tab bar on all pages of my site, and I use php to bring it in and change the appearance of the selected tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

Option 1: output a simple page with some JS that gets the browser specs and then does a redirect, passing those specs along as query args. e.g.

http://example.com/stage2.php?x=1024&y=768

This stage2 script can then build the real page based on the passed-along specs.

Option 2: Use some AJAX lazy loading. Primary content of the page gets the specs, passes them back via an AJAX call, and the response is the rest of the HTML, adjusted to reflect those specs. e.g

```
$('#body').load('example.com?x = ' + window.width + ......);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! that AJAX goes straight over my head, but the first idea seems clever. In fact, since the context is a photo gallery, I can avoid a redirect by having the first image load a default size, but use javascript to change the href of the "next" button with those args.
I don't think I have enough rep to rep you

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a simpler way to do this. You can set up css media queries to load a different image based on viewport width.

PHP doesn't know much about the client. Getting information like viewport sizes is difficult.

Comment: can't beleive I missed those before! thanks for bringing them to my attention. much easier than changing the src of an img.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that would require me having to use a div with a background image, rather than an img? because that's not so good for SEO I don't think.
Even so, thanks for the help, you couldn't have known SEO was a priority. I don't think I can rep you since I just joined the site..

Comment: You are correct, you would need to use a div with background image. I'm not sure what kind of seo benefit you are expecting to get out of images other than getting indexed by google images.

Comment: ah, well I'm a hobbyist visual artist, so it would be nice to be indexed by google images. I should've stated in my original question.

Comment: The one thing that you need to be aware of is that googles robot doesn't have any viewport or may not run javascript. If you want the images to be indexed by google, you will have to have some sort of fallback that can be used by google, on top of which your solution that will be used by users.

Comment: you're exactly right. on my current javascript version, no images are indexed, because none exist until javascript has acted. I'll be sure to build in a fallback - a default image size for when there is no viewport. Thanks for your help.