# Is there a way to test Bootstrap 3 viewport size in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I know I can use CSS to hide elements in Bootstrap 3 like this

```
<div class="hidden-sm">Hidden Content</div>
```

I also know that I can test the viewport size in Javascript like this:

```
if $(window).width() < 640 {
    // hide this content
}
```

What I'm curious to know is, is there any PHP function to test the viewport size? Specifically, what is the best practice for determining the current Bootstrap 3 viewport class in a Wordpress context? It would be great if there was a function like this:

```
if ( is_viewport_sm() ) {
    // hide this content
    // run this loop
}
```

I know there are [AJAX workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839746/conundrum-need-to-get-viewport-size-in-php-or-any-other-way-around-it), but I figured someone might have some plugin or function to address such a common challenge.

Comment: i believe not, since PHP is a server sided language, I don't think it is aware of any screen size, etc. The best you can probably do is to assume a screen size via user-agent, but that is not reliable.

Comment: common challenge? viewport size is a client side property which should/needs to be handled using client side techniques (CSS, Javascirpt) that's why you're using a framework like Bootstrap

Comment: ok, thanks for @kennypu and koala_dev clarifying.